# most efficient way to add a calculated field mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Hi I have a fairly large dataset 55K records. I am calculating the moving average for those. Which is the most efficient way to store these results again?

Currently I am doing this. Which leads to extreme amount of records being written one by one. Is there a way for me to write the whole list back in one call if I add the calculated value to the records array?

updated the code with the bulk update. It however fails to update the "MA16" record. Even though I know for sure that there is valid data in the "list" array.

It seems to match the documents but won't update. It will yield a MA16 field in the database that is always null.

```
Logged output. 
deletedCount:0
insertedCount:0
insertedIds:Object {}
matchedCount:150
modifiedCount:0
n:0
nInserted:0
nMatched:150
nModified:0
nRemoved:0
nUpserted:0
ok:1

var bulkUpdateArray = _.map(records, (record, index) => {
                    return {
                        updateOne :{
                            "filter":{_id : record._id},
                            "update":{$set: {"MA16": list[index]}},
                            "upsert":true
                        }
                    }
                });

                mongoose.connection.db.collection(req.body.day).bulkWrite(bulkUpdateArray).then(result => {
                    console.log("Insert result", result);
                }).catch(err=>{
                    //catch the error here
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use BulkWrite to achieve what you want.

Try this:

```
var bulkUpdateArray = _.map(records, (record, index) => {
    return {
        updateOne :{
            "filter":{_id : record._id},
            "update":{$set: {"MA16": list[index]}},
            "upsert":true
        }
    }
})

mongoose.connection.db.collection(req.body.day).bulkWrite(bulkUpdateArray).then(result => {
    //check the result of bulk update here
}).catch(err=>{
    //catch the error here
})
```

You can use `updateOne` operator of `bulkWrite`.

From official MongoDB docs, bulkWrite has following options:

```
{ updateOne :
      {
         "filter" : <document>,
         "update" : <document>,
         "upsert" : <boolean>,
         "collation": <document>,
         "arrayFilters": [ <filterdocument1>, ... ]
      }    
}
```

Please read [MongoDB bulkWrite documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite) for more info.

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Sounds like an excellent way of doing it! Will update my code and test before accepting answer.

Comment: Yeah give it a try, I hope this will work out for you

Comment: Ran into problems with the field being null

Comment: Which field is null?

Comment: There is no field that's empty it's in the DB it ends empty.  "update":{$set: {"MA16": list[index]}}, will yield Null in DB. If I log it in the return function list[index] does have a value

Comment: I assume the match count means it has found ID matches? matchedCount:150

Comment: Sorry just me being stupid. It's supposed to be null until 16 values have been calculated of course since it's MA16.